# Subtitle appearing in Acm Reference Format

Tags: titles, acm

I'm writing an article for ACM Conference and I'm using portuguese as main language. In this specific Conference they allow it but I have to write two titles, the first in english and the second in portuguese. The main problem is that in "box" Acm Reference Format I need show only the english title, however as this is generated automatically, it compiled the two titles. I'm writing like this:

```
\begin{document}


\title{Hermes: A Natural Language Interface Model for Software Transformation}

\subtitle{Hermes: Um Modelo de Interface de Linguagem Natural para Transformação em Software 
}
```

Can you help me with this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Logically Portuguese title is not a subtitle.  I'd rather think it is a note.  So my suggestion would be

```
\title{Hermes: A Natural Language Interface Model for Software Transformation}

\titlenote{Hermes: Um Modelo de Interface de Linguagem Natural para Transformação em Software}
```